# MySQL select where duplicates in field, not returning all records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select records where the record shares a field value with another record, but the query I am trying only returns one occurrence. For example, in this table:

```
COUNTRY         LANGUAGE
Mexico          Spanish
Portugal        Portuguese
Russia          Russian
Spain           Spanish
Thailand        Thai
United Kingdom  English
United States   English
```

... I would like to return:

```
COUNTRY         LANGUAGE
Mexico          Spanish
Spain           Spanish
United Kingdom  English
United States   English
```

Using:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `language` HAVING COUNT(language) > 1
```

I only get:

```
COUNTRY         LANGUAGE
Spain           Spanish
United Kingdom  English
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `language` IN (
    SELECT * GROUP BY `language` HAVING COUNT(primary_language) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to break this up into two steps.  Get the list of languages in a sub-select, then get the rows:

SELECT * FROM country_language where language in (SELECT language FROM country_language GROUP BY language HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

Answer (score 1):

try this

> SELECT COUNTRY, LANGUAGE FROM `table` WHERE LANGUAGE IN (SELECT LANGUAGE FROM `table` GROUP BY `language` HAVING COUNT(language) > 1);

Answer (score 1):

You need a sub query that returns the set of languages that have multiple countries speaking them. Then select all of the rows whose language is in that set:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE language IN
(
  SELECT language FROM `table` GROUP BY `language` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that experienced with having but this should do the trick!

```
SELECT Country
from (SELECT Country, count(Lang) as Langs
FROM Land
Group by Lang) as table2
WHERE table2.Langs!=1
```